# Is there a way to have an absolute positioned element with higher z-index over top another element but still able to hover over the element behind it?

Tags: html, css, fade, linear-gradients, absolute

I have a div with the class "fullheightcolumn" with a height of 100vh and containing an img. I want the top of the page to fade to black, so I added another div with the class "fadedblack" and wrote the following css:

```
.fadedblack {
  height: 50vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%);
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  width:  100%;
}
```

This works well, but I have a hover effect on the class fullheightcolumn. When I hover over the bottom 50% of the page, the hover effect works. If I go higher, it stops because obviously I'm hovering over the fadedblack element. Is there a way to effectively "lock" the fadedblack element so it's still visible, but when I hover over it, the browser recognizes it as hovering over the element behind it? Is there another way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: `pointer-events:none` ?

Comment: Thank you! Worked beautifully. I didn’t know about pointer-events property.